# Find synonyms words

Tags: java

How to extract the synonym words the file of elements in Array?

I was able to read from the file, but the elements given in the array are matched in the file, but I want the elements given in the array to show the synonym words of the elements from the file, that is, the synonym word of the element will be shown.

```java
package file;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

        // Read the words from the file and add them to the ArrayList
        try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\File\\src\\file\\words.txt"))) {
            while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
                words.add(fileScanner.next());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }

        String wordToFind = "apple";
        String another = "mango";
        int index = words.indexOf(wordToFind);

        if (index != -1) {
            // Get the content of the element at the index
            String content = words.get(index);
            // Print the synonyms of the element
            String[] synonyms = getSynonyms(content);

            for (String synonym : synonyms) {
                System.out.println(synonym);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("The word " + wordToFind + " was not found in the ArrayList");
        }
    }

    public static String[] getSynonyms(String word) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to return the synonyms of the given word
        return new String[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: How are the contents of the file formatted?

Comment: just normal add...like word apple,x(here x is synonym need)

Comment: How is your file looking alike?

Comment: @Jakariaalamsaimon, so what you want is to split the String into an array by comma?